# I want to automate a audio/video calls of a web application using selenium. Is it posible? If so Can someone share any insight or idea?

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, webautomation

My requirement is to autonmate a audio/video calls through selenium. Can someone help me in building a framework of audio /video calls automation testing

Scenario:
Its like two user joins a audio/video meeting in common room.
They can perform basic call operations like video audio mute/unmute, screenshare, end call.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

No Selenium is for UI automation. If you have the web application for your app, you can automate that.

### Selenium automates browsers. That's it!

What you do with that power is entirely up to you.

Primarily it is for automating web applications for testing purposes, but is certainly not limited to just that.

Boring web-based administration tasks can (and should) also be automated as well.